# RxJava: merge BehaviorSubjects

Tags: android, java-8, rx-java, rx-java2

How to merge two `BehaviorSubject`s so they behave like a single `BehaviorSubject`?

I have something like this:

```
class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Subject<List<Integer>> left = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
        Subject<List<Integer>> right = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6));
        Single<List<Integer>> merged = left.mergeWith(right).reduce(new ArrayList<Integer>(), (l, r) -> {
            List<Integer> merged1 = new ArrayList<>(l.size() + r.size());
            merged1.addAll(l);
            merged1.addAll(r);
            return merged1;
        });
        merged.subscribe(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

I expect to get somthing `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`, but `subscribe` prints nothing.

Comment: First, why do you want to do this? Second, `reduce` requires finite sequences to produce the final result but your subjects never complete.

Comment: `mergeWith` works perfectly with `BehaviorSubjects`, the problem probably lies in the `reduce`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work ;)

```
Subject<List<Integer>> left = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
Subject<List<Integer>> right = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6));
Observable<List<Integer>> merged = Observable.zip(left, right, (value1, value2) -> {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.addAll(value1);
    list.addAll(value2);
    return list;
});
merged.subscribe(System.out::println);
```